# Disable timer interrupts in kernel source for mode switching in ARM

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, arm, interrupt, armv7

I have a small function which I have added in kernel source (linux 3.0) which does some task and works fine in SVC mode. But in interrupt mode (i.e., when timer interrupts are enabled in kernel through `local_irq_enable`) it does not work. So I am thinking of switching to SVC mode before executing my function. I have taken code for switching modes from one of the posts.

```c
void myfunction(..some args)
{ 
    unsigned int oldmode = get_cpsr() & 0x1f;

    if (oldmode == 18) // Check for IRQ mode
        change_mode(MODE_SVC);
    // ...My code ....
    restore_mode(oldmode);
}
```

Definitions are as follows:

```c
#define MODE_IRQ        0x12
#define MODE_SVC        0x13

#define change_mode(mode) asm("cps %0" : : "I"(mode))

#define restore_mode(mode) \
    mode &= 0x1f; \
    asm(" msr cpsr, %0\n" : : "r"(mode) : "cc")

static inline unsigned int get_cpsr(void)
{
    unsigned int val;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (" mrs %0, cpsr\n"
                          : "=r" (val));
    return val;
}
```

Even after this I am not getting correct output. Function execution gets stuck somewhere. I have debugged the address where it gets stuck and it is pointing to these symbols of **System.map**

`__exception_text_start
 _stext
 asm_do_IRQ`

Is my usage of function correct. Can you suggest me any other solution for this problem. I am running this image then on ARMv7 board. And lastly there are **calls to some kernel APIs like `printch()` in my function after changing mode**.

Comment: @artlessnoise Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534450/how-does-ftrace-track-interrupt-service-routines).  I think you have some mis-conceptions.  ARM Linux almost never executes in IRQ mode.  The most likely issue is *My code* has something which is non-re-entrant, including other functions called by your code.

Comment: @artlessnoise But where is timer interrupt handled then.The code works fine before timer interrupt comes.I found the last functions that were executed and which kept repeating were : `handle_edge_irq` -> `_raw_spin_lock` -> `__raw_spin_lock` -> `add_preempt_count` -> `sub_preempt_count`. Could you point out where might it be going wrong. And the exception I stated comes after call to `gic_irq`.

Comment: @notlikethat Any points on the matter. There is also irq_check_poll that is being called inside `handle_edge_irq`.